# Android to PC connection via USB

Tags: java, android

I would like to create an application for PC that can access my application on an Android phone and give commands to it. I created an android application that uses the SIM card what i would like to do is a desktop application that connects to my application via USB and can give commands to it from my desktop app. Could you give me a good place to start? 
Sow what i need is

**1 Connect android app to desktop app via USB**

**2 Command the android app from desktop app**